# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() with XAMP and PHP 7

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to enable SQL Drivers.
I'm using xamp my version of php is  7.1.10 and Architecture x86
I installed the version 4 of SQL Drivers, and moved the files to the extesions folder and I have this in the php.ini

```
extesion=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll
extesion=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll
```

And I'm getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\diplomado\conection.php:4 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\diplomado\index.php(17): include() #1 {main} thrown in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\diplomado\conection.php on line 4
```

and this is my php file

```
$serverName= "localhost";
$conectionInfo = array("DataBase"=>"prueba","UID"=>"Root", "UPW"=>"");
$con = sqlsrv_connect($servername,$conectionInfo);
if ($con){
echo "Succesful";
}else{
echo "failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: Does [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) say everything is cool?

Comment: Yes everything is fine

Comment: Clearly it's not, so there's a disconect then between what that's reporting as loaded and what's actually loaded. You may need to inspect what's actually in that DLL as far as functions go, or see if other functions that should be there are defined.

Comment: I checked it, and everything seems fine

Comment: Can you connect using PDO and a SQL Server DSN?

Comment: Nope I can't d o that

Comment: Why not? PDO is a better option unless you're maintaining legacy code.